# What is "call stack" in remix ide debugger and how it is calculated?

Tags: remix

in remix ide (based on https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_debug.html):

1. deploy any smart contract
2. in remix logs you -> for transaction that created a new smart contract -> click "debug" button

[image]

you will see the "unnamed" call stack - that's ok

3. run any smart contract function and click "debug" for this new transaction

[image]

You will see some hash

Question:

- how this hash in constructed?

there is no info about how it should be constructed in the "Yellow Paper"

the best approximation I have found is this https://github.com/dapphub/dapptools/blob/a2b96cc2dbc28508c9fe699d6438bf6eccafc2ad/src/hevm/src/EVM.hs#L224-L238

Answer (score 0):

I have found, it's just the address of contract i'm currently in

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]